# Establish an empty variable for future use?

Tags: python, variables

I want to be able to establish a variable with no value in order to fill it in at a later point in my code, based upon the output of another function.
Ex:

```
variable = ""
...20 lines later...
if function() is 10:
    variable = "10"
else:
    variable = "5"

print(variable + 20)
```

Here's my code so far:

```
yahoo = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
hotmail = "smtp.live.com"

def smtpServer():
    if "@yahoo.com" in username:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(yahoo,587)
    if "@hotmail.com" in username:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(hotmail,587)
    else:
        pass

def check():
    try:
        server.connect(server)
        server.login(username,password)
        server.quit()

line = f.readline()
    cnt = 1
    while line:
        #UserAndPass = str.split(':') #check login
        UserAndPass = line.split(':')
        username = str(UserAndPass[0])
        password = str(UserAndPass[1])
        cnt += 1
        server = ""
        smtpServer()
        check()
```

With what I have now, I keep getting errors saying that it's undefined, so I'm just not sure how to define it for this purpose. Thank you!

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick but `variable + 20` won't work because variable is a `str` and 20 is an `int`. Also `function() is 10` is really strange because checking number equality is normally done with `==`

Comment: "it's undefined" _What_ is undefined? What part of your second code is related to your first?

Comment: @AK47 Then he should say so in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer a global variable from within a function, you need to declare it using `global yahoo` or `global hotmail` in your function. You also need to declare `global server` in the functions setting and using the server.

You don't need to initialize the variable to an empty value for this to work.

However, your approach of hardcoding the mail servers for mail addresses is completely broken. Use the MX records provided by the domain name system, they're there for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

Use this for making an empty variable:

```
variable = None
```

For your code, you can use `server = None`.